# pip install lapjv failed

Tags: visual-studio, installation, pip

I installed under Python 3.6.13
I tried to install build tools or even uninstall VS and then reinstall it, but it didn't work. This problem always exists.

```
Running setup.py clean for lapjv
Failed to build lapjv
Installing collected packages: lapjv
    Running setup.py install for lapjv ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\DeepBindff\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lrnqbqb1\\lapjv_d7aa7e022bf14ef3b147d3c1a5d
34efe\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lrnqbqb1\\lapjv_d7aa7e022bf14ef3b147d3c1a5d34efe\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file_
_) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-record-pyjon60w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\DeepBindff\Include\lapjv'
         cwd: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lrnqbqb1\lapjv_d7aa7e022bf14ef3b147d3c1a5d34efe\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'lapjv' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\DeepBindff\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lrnqbqb1\\
lapjv_d7aa7e022bf14ef3b147d3c1a5d34efe\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lrnqbqb1\\lapjv_d7aa7e022bf14ef3b147d3c1a5d34efe\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__
file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record
'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pyjon60w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\DeepBindff\Include\lapjv' Check the logs for full command out
put.
```

Comment: I use VS2019.    Lapjv seems to have no corresponding whl file.It seems that it can be successfully installed under the Linux system

Comment: In fact, I installed Microsoft Visual c++build tools and found them in the control panel, but they still didn't work.